# Upload File with UTF-8 filename Issue

Tags: batch-file, utf-8, cmd

i want upload my files to FTP server using with Windows conmand prompt. It working good if the filename doesn't contain UTF-8 Characters. But If it contains UTF-8 Characters not uploading to FTP service.
My test.bat :

```
@echo off

chcp 65001
echo >> %TMP%\ab.dat
echo user b12_17312633> %TMP%\ab.dat
echo 123456ab>> %TMP%\ab.dat
echo bin>> %TMP%\ab.dat
echo cd htdocs>> %TMP%\ab.dat

for /R %1 %%f in (*.txt) do (
    echo put "%%f">> %TMP%\ab.dat
    )

echo bye>> %TMP%\ab.dat
echo quit>> %TMP%\ab.dat
ftp -n -s:%TMP%\ab.dat ftp.byethost12.com
pause
```

Output:

```
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 456 of 1900 allowed.
220-Local time is now 20:57. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220 You will be disconnected after 60 seconds of inactivity.
ftp> user b12_17312633
331 User b12_17312633 OK. Password required

230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
ftp> bin
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
ftp> cd htdocs
250 OK. Current directory is /htdocs
ftp> put "C:\Users\user\Desktop\FTP\Ã§tÃ¼.txt"
C:\Users\user\Desktop\FTP\Ã§tÃ¼.txt: File not foundftp> bye
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout.
```

I tried it on "çtü.txt" for test.
Note: I worked this on Windows Command Prompt.

Comment: which FTP client are you using?

Comment: Sorry, i'm beginner. I don't understand you as good. My FTP server Pure-FTPd. I am using CMD for connect FTP server.

Comment: Never mind. Non-ASCII filenames require the server and client to support UTF-8 filename mode (RFC 264). Pure-FTP server does, but as Windows hasn't shipped a command-line FTP client for many years, I doubt your client does. You may have luck with ncftp, Cygwin's FTP client or perhaps a different protocol altogether like SFTP.

Comment: Hmm, Then I am going to use another FTP client . Thank's for the information :)

Comment: Please take a look at my updated answer. It should work for you now.

Answer (score 0):

> - `-s:<FileName>` Specifies a text file that contains `ftp` commands. These commands run automatically after ftp starts. This parameter
>     allows no spaces. Use this parameter instead of redirection (<).
> - **Note**. In Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 or later operating systems, the text file must be written in `UTF-8`.

[`FTP` documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff687787.aspx) **conceals** that this text file must be written in `UTF-8` **with BOM** (byte order mark) although according to the Unicode standard, the [BOM for `UTF-8` files is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223926/3439404).

I'd use next improvement of your `test.bat` script:

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
powershell -command [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("'%TMP%\ab.dat'", (0xEF,0xBB,0xBF))
echo user b12_17312633>> %TMP%\ab.dat
rem … the script continues here
```

where `powershell` call creates the `ab.dat` file with [`UTF-8` BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8), i.e. with initial / leading byte sequence `0xEF`,`0xBB`,`0xBF`.

Comment: The problem doesn't at file content. It is at file name. Also my file already using UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: @RecepSelimAğırman did you try my solution? [Take a look](ftp://ftp.byethost12.com/htdocs/), you should see a file `tçtü.txt` uploaded with your script improved as I have suggested…

Comment: Yes, i tried now it. Yo're right. I saw tçtü.txt. Well, now how do I get the results I want? I mean, it doesn't work on my computer.

Comment: Double check the `utf8bom.txt` file and check `%TMP%\ab.dat` using a hexadecimal viewer/editor whether it contains UTF-8 BOM. Note `>>` redirector in `echo user b12_17312633>> %TMP%\ab.dat`. Or try command line `chcp 437` and then `type %TMP%\ab.dat` it should return `∩╗┐user b12_17312633` at the first line.

Comment: It shows:
`C:\Users\user>chcp 437
Etkin kod sayfasi: 437

C:\Users\user>type %TMP%\ab.dat
user b12_17312633
123456ab
binary
cd htdocs
put "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Recep Selim\FTP\testttt.txt"
put "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Recep Selim\FTP\utf8.txt"
put "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Recep Selim\FTP\├ºt├╝.txt"
bye
quit

C:\Users\user>`

Comment: I guess so, problem at this `C:\Users\user\Desktop\Recep Selim\FTP\├ºt├╝.txt`

Comment: Also my .txt files at main directory. So it's at program directory. Not `%TMP%`

Comment: Again: the FTP script file, i.e. `%TMP%\ab.dat` need to contain UTF-8 byte order mark, i.e. must start with three bytes  0xEF,0xBB,0xBF. Those bytes _appear_ as `∩╗┐` when you `type` such file  under `chcp 437`.

Comment: Result is same. It doesn't appear `∩╗┐`.

Comment: Please do not show what does not appear. Just **force** the BOM as suggested. Double check (see and follow my comment 45 min. ago above)…

Comment: Okey, i forced it to UTF-8 - BOM (I used Notepad++). CMD appears `∩╗┐` for now. But Script doesn't still upload `çtü.txt`.

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35415997/edit) and add the newest version of your _batch_ script `test.bat`.  Also now under `chcp 65001` and with proper BOM in FTP script `type %TMP%\ab.dat` should show `put "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Recep Selim\FTP\çtü.txt"` just before `bye` instead of mojibake `├ºt├╝.txt`

Answer (score 0):

In windows10 check this Control Panel-> Small icons-> Region-> Change system locale-> Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support

Comment: Same problem: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/zh-cn/6b4df752-51d1-42fb-baf1-8600fa0bdfc5/utf8-encoding-bug-report-about-using-ftp-with-windows-explorer?referrer=https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/zh-cn/6b4df752-51d1-42fb-baf1-8600fa0bdfc5/utf8-encoding-bug-report-about-using-ftp-with-windows-explorer